# What (if anything) should I do with this wooden foundation beam?

Tags: foundation

We live in a very old house and have this beam in the foundation. It's under a soffit, but (as you can see) does get wet when it's sufficiently windy. It doesn't look rotten and I've no idea how long it's been there, could be decades (basement was finished by the previous owner ~20 years ago but I don't think they touched the foundation; the house itself is 100+ years old and the age of the foundation is unknown).

What should I do about it? Should I paint/seal it? Dig and check what's underground and if it's rotting?
We have a finished basement, so I cannot check it from the inside without dismantling a wall.
[image]

Comment: How wide is that wood piece? My first instinct is that it was a post holding the house up while a new foundation was placed.

Answer (score 1):

That's not a beam. That's two vertical boards (notice the direction of the grain in the wood and fairly obvious dividing line roughly down the middle) that were put into a foundation vent to close it off.

That wasn't a 100% professional way of closing off the foundation vent (that's a nice way of saying it's a DIY hack). Odds are good that if you pull them out, you'll find some insulation (if you're lucky) and the back side of the drywall (or whatever it is) that's finishing your basement. Based on the weathering, those boards have been there for a mighty long time. Probably the 20+ years since the previous owner did the basement work.

They'll probably last another 20 years before they rot out to the point that they *really* need to be replaced. However, the "proper" thing to do would be to replace them with something more appropriate for ground contact. You could pull them out to ensure that there is insulation behind them, then replace them with:

- One piece of (ground contact rated) pressure treated lumber.
- A concrete paver of approximately the same color as the foundation.
- A couple of bricks (they make bricks in grey that might be pretty close in color).

There are probably other options I'm not thinking of. In any case, you'd want to use an appropriate caulk (or concrete adhesive if using a cementitious material) to hold them in place and keep the water out.

You could just leave the boards alone and keep an eye on them until they've obviously rotted out. You could also caulk around all the edges then apply a coat of paint to them.